# Position of a particle in the standard infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

If one made many measurements of the position of a particle in the standard infinite well and binned the result to estimate $P_{CL}(x)$, what would the result look like?

What would it look like for a particle that was undergoing simple harmonic motion? or a ball bouncing vertically under the influence of gravity?

---

My attempt at the answer:

[image]

---

I am struggling the understand what the question is asking and how to continue my answer?

Comment: I suspect $P_\text{CL}(x)$ is asking for the *classical* probability distribution for such a problem. In other words, if you had a particle bumping around inside a box, the question is asking that if you chose a random instant of time, what is the probability that you will find the particle at a specific location classically. Does the question ask you specifically to do it quantum mechanically? The reason I'm suspicious is because it also asks you to do this for a bouncing ball, which is a very difficult question to solve in an introductory QM course.

Comment: Thank you, that would make the first part easier to answer. how would i find the classical probability for a particle undergoing SHM, as it longer has a constant horizontal velocity

Comment: This is an under-specified question. What is the state function at $t=0$? If it's a mixture of eigenstates, then the distribution isn't constant in time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability density of finding a particle at a position $x$ is just $|\psi(x)|^2$. The question doesn't specify which state so let's take the ground state $u_1(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin(\frac{\pi x}{a})$. The probability of finding density it at $x$ is simply $\frac{2}{a}\sin^2(\frac{\pi x}{a})$ inside the box and zero everywhere else.

To find the classic distribution we have to somehow average over time. The probability of finding a particle at $x$ is proportional to the time it spends there. If a particle is moving slow at some location it will spend a lot of time there and the probability of finding it at that location will be high.
$$p(x)\sim\Delta t\approx\frac{\Delta x}{v}$$
So to get a probability function define $f(x)=\frac{N}{v(x)}$ with $N$ a normalization constant. To have a proper probability distribution you should have $\int_a^b f(x)dx=1$.

You can use conservation of energy to write $v$ as a function of $x$. For the infinite well this becomes $v=\sqrt\frac{2E}{m}$. For a general potential this becomes $$v(x)=\sqrt{\frac{2(E-U(x))}{m}}$$

For the infinite square well it is easy to see the difference: for classical particles the probability distribution is flat (it's a constant) but the quantum probability has bumps.

Comment: See also sections 6.2 and 6.3 [here](https://www.compadre.org/PQP/quantum-theory/section6_2.cfm), where they have some nice animations explaining this in more detail. The OP might find the examples in section 6.3 to be particularly helpful.